# JDBC connection in Java with Eclipse ( when a method calling a method)

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to my DB using JDBC. I wanted to make a method for connection and another method for selecting data.  I am getting a red line in Eclipse on the 'Connection con = connectDB();'  part. ( See also attached)  Cany anyone give me advice?

`public class DBJdbc {`

```
 //Statement stmt = null;

// connecting to DB
public void connectDB() {            

    //Connection con = null;

    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://****/SAC?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "***", "***");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}   

// a method for selecting DB
public static  void select() { 

    //connectDB(); 

    String sql = "SELECT * from SAC_SUR";

        try(Connection con = connectDB();  // I'm getting a red line here) 
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql)){
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt(1);
                String name = rs.getString(2);
                System.out.println("Id = " + id + "name = " + name);
            } //while 
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

[red line here!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9bge.jpg)

Comment: Return type of `connectDB()` is `void`, meaning there is no return value, so what did you expect `Connection con = connectDB()` to assign to `con`?

Comment: Why do you have two Statement objects, `pstmt` and `stmt`, with the same `sql`?

Comment: Since you're using try-with-resources, you should also use it on the `ResultSet` object.

Comment: @Andreas  oops. thank you~

Comment: @Andreas   So instead of rs ,  I change it to 'con'?

Comment: *"So instead of rs , I change it to 'con'?"* I don't understand. `rs` and `con` aren't even the same type, so how can `rs` be changed to `con`? Don't know how you even got that out of what I've said.

Comment: @Andreas   ah~  okay.  I'm learning a lot from you. thank you.  I will re-read and try to understand the true meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

connectDB() method is of void type and not returning anything but when you are calling the method, you are assigning it to variable con. So you need to change the return type of connectDb to the Connection type.

```
public Connection connectDB() {            

    Connection con = null;

    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 

         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://****/SAC?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "***", "***");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return con;
}
```

Comment: If either of those `catch` clauses are invoked, that code will lead the `NullPointerException` once code reached `con.prepareStatement(sql)`

Comment: @Andreas   Andreas,  I got NullPointerException like you said :(  How can I fix this? Please give me more hint.

Comment: @Pooja Aggarwal   okay~~ I'm quite new to this. sorry.

Comment: @JinLee Don't catch exception and continue as-if nothing went wrong. Basically, don't catch exception.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call non-static method into the static area, which is not allowed in Java. So I made this method static and returning the database connection.

Please update the below method into your code. It will resolve your problem.

```
public static Connection connectDB() { 
    Connection con = null; 
    try { 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://****/SAC?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "", ""); 
    } catch(SQLException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return con; 
}
```